# MagicalRecord - fetch objects grouped by month/year

Tags: iphone, database, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a number of `Game` objects, each one having a `date` parameter.

In my controller I want to fetch those games, grouped by the `month`-`year` combination of their dates - so I can get a list of months, and for each month - a list of the games that happened in that month.

Is there a simple solution for this, without having to modify my CoreData model?

Answer (score 0):

[Custom Section Titles with NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) - this sample project shows how to do this (if I understood you correctly). Obviously, it doesn't use MagicalRecord, but it should be easy to port to MR.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

in your

```
model.h
```

add

```
-(NSString *)yearMonth;
```

and

`model.m`

```
-(NSString *)yearMonth
{
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM"];

   NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.eventDate];
   return formattedDateString;
}
```

Then call a MR_Fetch by group method like this:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [model MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"yearMonth" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"eventDate" ascending:NO];
```